# Convert NSDictionary value (id?) to NSString or NSNumber to compare it

Tags: objective-c, json, compare, nsdictionary

pls help me with my trouble:
I can't compare to value to know successful result was or not.
I fetch json-object as NSDictionaty:

```
    NSDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject                                                                                                                                       options:0 error:nil];
```

And after that I get value for key: code

```
    [returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"];
```

If returning value is equal 1 so that's OK, but problem is that I don't know the type value of key "code". I tried to compare id, NSString, NSNumber but all were fail. What type of object should I compare ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you use the comparison operator (`==`) to compare your objects?

If so, you didn't compare the values of your objects but their memory addresses.
If the object returned by `[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"]` is of type `NSString` you should use `NSString's isEqualToString:` 
If it returns a `NSNumber` instance, you could compare the `intValue` of that object to 1.

```
[[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] isEqualToString:@"1"]
```

or

```
[[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] intValue] == 1
```

Comment: Thank a lot Weichsel !. intValue really helps me.

Comment: Minor remark: `intValue` is available for `NSString` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

to check the class of the object pulled from the dictionary.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the output to be an integer, you can call `intValue`.

`[[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] intValue] == 1`

Also, you can log the type of the returned object by `+ class;` method.

`NSLog(@"%@", [[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] class]);`

Answer (score 0):

put in a breakpoint and print out the classname...

type into the debugger: `po [[returnDictionary objectForKey:@"code"]className]`

that will give you the class, something like `_NSCFString` will be a string etc...

Answer (score 0):

`id` is something of a "cheat" in Objective-C, though one that is officially "blessed".  Generally, where a method returns `id` you can directly use that value to invoke a method on the returned type, without having to first cast to the appropriate type -- the compiler knows to suppress "can't find that method name" type warnings/errors when the call is on an `id`.

Of course, if you don't know the class of the object, you don't know whose methods to call.  As Pablo suggests you can use isKindOfClass to test, if you have a suspicion.  Alternatively, you can log the class name of an object with `NSLog(@"The class is %s", object_getClassName(someId));` or one or two other ways.